Transfer data from one form to another in powerapps. The two forms submit to two different sharepointlists but have almost similar datacard values
I am currently designing an inventory management app in powerapps. I am trying to pass data from one form to another form on different screens. These forms are connected to two different SharePoint lists. The data source of Form1 is the Equipment list and the data source of form6 is transferred sharepointlist.

On this screen there is a gallery(Records1Gallery)where form1 gets the items, that is whenever an item is selected in the gallery the form reflects these particular fields. I want to transfer these fields from this screen to the transferred screen in form6.

On the equipment list screen I have a button: Transfer and on the Onselect property I have put:
EditForm(Form1);
Navigate(
    Transfer,
    ScreenTransition.None,
    {
        SelectedDesignation: Filter(
            'Equipment list',
            Designation = ThisRecord.Designation
        )
    }
)


On the transferred Screen, I have a form(form6) whose data source is transferred SharePoint list. On the items property of form6 I have put:
RecordsGallery1.Selected

But this returns an error. How can I solve that?

Since datasource of your both forms are different, you can not fill your second form with the datasource of first gallery/form.
